# C# DateTime List with Null

Tags: c#, sorting, datetime, nullable

I have a list of DateTime and null values that I want to sort. It looks something like this.

```
List<DateTime?> allDateTimes = new List<DateTime?>();
allDateTimes.Add(new DateTime(2015, 12, 31, 5, 10, 20));
allDateTimes.Add(Null);
allDateTimes.Add(new DateTime(2014, 11, 15, 5, 10, 20));
allDateTimes.Add(new DateTime(2014, 11, 18, 5, 10, 20));
```

How would I do to sort this by earliest date and null at last place. I have tried something like this

```
allDateTimes.Sort((a, b) => a.CompareTo(b));
```

and

```
allDateTimes.Sort((a, b) => a.HasValue.CompareTo(b));
```

But I cant Sort this way because of the null values.

Comment: What problems you are having?

Comment: "I keep having problems" - what problems?

Comment: @Adam Lundberg `allDateTimes.Sort((DateTime? a, DateTime? b) => 
        DateTime.Compare(a ?? DateTime.MaxValue, b ?? DateTime.MaxValue));` may work for [you](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ThSsZi).